# Real Fullscreen with Android 4 Tablets

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

i'm searching for a solution to make a tablet with ICS to fullscreen without navigation bar.

I have found an app "GestureControl" that make that possible. But there are some other things in this app that I doesn't need. So I think it is possible.

I tried some things with "FLAG_FULLSCREEN" or " SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION" but it doesn't work. Maybe I use it not correctly.

Have anyone a solution for my problem?

Much thanks.

Comment: I answered a similar question in:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445157/easy-way-to-hide-system-bar-on-android-ics/16401655#16401655

my solution is to edit a special file `BUILD.PROP` in the android file system. It's not a solution for everyone, but it could helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide the system bar on Android tablets, except perhaps on rooted devices.

> I have found an app "GestureControl" that make that possible. But there are some other things in this app that I doesn't need. So I think it is possible.

GestureControl only works on rooted devices.

Comment: Yes my device is rooted. I have a lite version of that app and i only want to have this feature. So how it is possible with a root device?

Comment: @user1211297 You can try HideBar app, I have the same case and it works well for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926767/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-navigation-bar-in-android-ics/13432062#13432062

Answer (score -1):

U can not hide the Systembar in Android, except on rooted devices.
The app u mentioned is for rooted devices only.

sry about that.