# How to hide the soft-key bar on Android phone?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

[image]

When my app starts, I'd like to hide the soft keys bar (in red rectangle) to have a larger screen.

1. How can I hide it?
2. Do I need to show the bar purposely when the app quits? Or it will restore itself automatically after the app quits?

Android 4.1, with no hardware keys on phone front.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide System Bar in Tablets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605266/hide-system-bar-in-tablets)

Comment: Also possibly helpful: [Easy way to hide system bar on Android ICS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445157/easy-way-to-hide-system-bar-on-android-ics)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

From official [doc](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html)

> The SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE flag replaces the STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN
>   flag. When set, this flag enables “low profile" mode for the system
>   bar or navigation bar. Navigation buttons dim and other elements in
>   the system bar also hide. Enabling this is useful for creating more
>   immersive games without distraction for the system navigation buttons.
>
> The SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE flag replaces the STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE flag
>   to request the system bar or navigation bar be visible.
>
> The SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION is a new flag that requests the
>   navigation bar hide completely. Be aware that this works only for the
>   navigation bar used by some handsets (it does not hide the system
>   bar on tablets). The navigation bar returns to view as soon as the
>   system receives user input. As such, this mode is useful primarily for
>   video playback or other cases in which the whole screen is needed but
>   user input is not required.

The behavior of the nav bar is app dependent IIRC, so it should show again after the user leaves your app.

Comment: Thanks! The above code hides the bar as expected. However, when I touch the screen of the active app, the bar will reappear. How can I make the bar hidden for the rest of the app life cycle?

Comment: Any time the user interacts with the app, the nav bar will come back, as you have seen.  This is, according to the official doc, intentional behavior.  I think you will have to hide the bar every time you expect an interaction, unfortunately.  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION

Comment: @MarsAtomic Since API level 19 there is SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE  and SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY

Answer (score 53):

I know its late but it is the right answer so what you are trying to do is what called immersive mode. for (API 19)

check out: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

The code that you were asking for is:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but I am facing issue when I open the keyboard , the bottom layouts are getting clipped .

Comment: @PraveenPandey you should add clippadding false tag .

Comment: Finally it's work. Code is everywere but the point is be in it onWindowFocusChanged. Thanks!

Comment: Although this does remove the navigation for me, the app is not using the unused space. Where the bar used to be is now just empty space. (I am using a NativeActivity.)

Comment: @Bram i think you shout set     android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
on your root layout

Comment: swipe from down to up

Comment: Thank you. Works regardless of user interaction.

Comment: @AbdulmalekDery you are welcome my collage friend :)