# How to remove bottom menu button in android 4.0 ICS

Tags: android, menu

I want to remove bottom menu button and I want to disable only particular class not in the all class in ICS. How can I achieve this?. Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: You mean disable in a particular `Activity`? Or you mean disable when the device is below ICS?

Comment: i mean disable only in a single activity

Comment: just i want to remove not in disable state

Comment: Duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291640/how-to-hide-the-soft-key-bar-on-android-phone/16291705#16291705.  Google and search in general are your friends.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the targetSdkVersion to 14 or above

> Blockquote
>   it's work ok but bitmap too large error

Answer (score 0):

Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/11438245/527759 but use

```
menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the targetSdkVersion to 14 or above

Answer (score 0):

Put following code in your manifest file.Its working for me.

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
         />
```