# Full Screen Theme for AppCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-theme

I would like to know how can I apply full screen theme ( no title bar + no actionbar ) to an activity. I am using AppCompat library from support package v7.

I've tried to applied `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` to my specific activity but it crashed. I think it's because my application theme is like this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

I also have tried this

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

which only hides title bar but not the action bar. 
My current workaround is that hiding the actionbar with

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: <h3>Answer With Output Screenshot</h3> [Here you can check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66492857/6159856)

Comment: <h3>Answer With Output Screenshot</h3> [Here you can check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66492857/6159856)

Answer (score 890, accepted):

When you use Theme.AppCompat in your application you can use FullScreenTheme by adding the code below to styles.

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and also mention in your manifest file.

```
<activity
   android:name=".activities.FullViewActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
/>
```

Comment: The parent style should be "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

Comment: Actually, it's enough to add this to the style xml file: <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>. The action bar (title bar) visibility can be separately controlled using .hide/.show methods at runtime.

Comment: FEATURE_NO_TITLE was not being honored.  Dunno the difference, but I finally changed my Activity to extend Activity instead of AppCompatActivity and my same code worked (thankfully I don't need AppCompat):        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

Comment: this hides status bar as well :(

Comment: I would add `hideNavigation()` in `onResume()` - without that, the navigation bar was still visible in my app (api 18+)

Comment: no need to set `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` if your theme includes `.NoActionBar`

Comment: Is there a list anywhere of all of the Theme.AppCompat variants?

Comment: I had to replace "android:windowNoTitle" with "windowNoTitle" for this to work.

Answer (score 74):

Based on the answer by @nebyan, I found that the action bar is still not hiding.

The following code works for me:

```
<style name="AppFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

and of course dont forgot to edit your `AndroidManifest` file.

```
<activity
    android:name="YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME"
    android:theme="@style/AppFullScreenTheme" 
/>
```

Comment: @nebyan why your solution does not work, and this one works for me? What is the reason?

Comment: no need to set `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` if your theme includes `.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 19):

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Using the above xml in style.xml, you will be able to hide the title as well as action bar.

Answer (score 13):

Issues arise among before and after versions of Android 4.0 (API level 14).

from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html) I created my own solution.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16)
    {
        // Hide the status bar
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        // Hide the action bar
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
    }
    else
    {
        // Hide the status bar
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        / Hide the action bar
        getActionBar().hide();
    }
}
```

I write this code in onResume() method because if you exit from your app and then you reopen it, the action bar remains active! (and so this fix the problem).

Comment: Notice that if user manually pull the status bar, it won't rehide itself. To make it worse, if soft keyboard is showing, status bar automatically shows as well and again, won't rehide.

Answer (score 7):

Your "workaround" (hiding the actionBar yourself) is the normal way. But google recommands to always hide the ActionBar when the TitleBar is hidden. Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html

Answer (score 7):

You can follow below step:-

AndoridMenifest.xml

```
<activity
            android:name=".ui.FullImageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@style/DialogTheme">
        </activity>
```

Style.xml

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">

    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>

   <!-- No backgrounds, titles or window float -->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

FullImageActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    setContentView(R.layout.image_view);
     }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //to remove "information bar" above the action bar
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    //to remove the action bar (title bar)
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To hide both status bar and action bar and make your activity full-screen use the following code in your activity's `onResume()` or `onWindowFocusChanged()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
}
```

You can find more Information in the following links:

- https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive#EnableFullscreen
- [Full Screen without navigation & status bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389547/full-screen-without-navigation-status-bars)
- [How to hide the soft-key bar on Android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291640/how-to-hide-the-soft-key-bar-on-android-phone)

**Note:** Using the xml solutions provide in this thread I could only hide the status bar but not the navigation bar.

Comment: Thank you, this is the only one hiding the navigation bar! Highly recommend this answer.

Answer (score 4):

This theme only works after API 21(included). And make both the StatusBar and NavigationBar transparent.

```
<style name="TransparentAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be **parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"**

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" 
parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Only this solution actually hides the title bar and makes it completely full screen. Should be marked as the correct solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can try the following** :

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove title bar in AppCompat:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: Please also explain code, if you provide it, it helps understanding your code and may help to gain insights for future problems.

Answer (score 0):

just this ?

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```