# AndroidStudio hide title bar crashes application

Tags: android

I'm trying to hide title bar in my app and I saw a lot of tutorials but none of them works, my app just crash immeditely.
This is my manifest. When I change from `@style/AppTheme` to `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar` it crashes app on my mobile phone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hr.com.thetta.www.pleasurre" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".PleasurreMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Logcat would be helpful here

Comment: I don't know how to use it, I can see it is empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your are using the support library, you should use

```
Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar
```

Instead of

```
Theme.NoActionBar
```

Comment: Your answer and this helped me alot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompact