# Why i get error when set fullscreen to my activity android?

Tags: android

I'm write this code for set fullscreen to my activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tologo);
        getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    }
```

but when i run the my app i get this error:

```
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
```

I'm write that code from this link:
[TUTORIAL](http://www.androidsnippets.com/how-to-make-an-activity-fullscreen)

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

to AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: @MohammedImranN i get this error Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: It seems to be correct, that error should appears if you call `setContentView()` before `requestWindowFeature()`.

Comment: Use this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat

Comment: Are you using Support Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Link [Full Screen Theme for AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat)

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onCreate()` method into this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
```