# Hide Android Action Bar solution

Tags: android, android-actionbar, hide

I've been looking for the solution to hide Android Action Bar. Tens of them are published and work the same way - Action Bar is hidden only after it's shown for the second. Not good enough, so I tested more and created my own solution. It was not published anywhere, but seems for me very simple and obvious. The most important is - Action Bar can't be seen at all.

My question is - what's wrong with it ? ) Why did Android dinosaurs avoid something like that ?

Solution to hide Android Action Bar :

in Manifest

```
 android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
```

in themes.xml

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">-50dp</item>
</style>
```

As you can see I just use negative marginBottom.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` - it completely removes the action bar as per its name.

Answer (score 1):

Use this `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`
And allow this in your style

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

For More information You may check SO Answer .I hope it will helps you .
[Full Screen Theme for AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `ActionBar` then you have use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` Theme.

Apply the following in your Theme for the Activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

You can hide `ActionBar` programatically also.

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); or getSupportActionBar();
 actionBar.hide();
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I made it work just changing **parent** value in `/res/values/style.xml`:

```
<resources>
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  </style>
</resources>
```

That worked for me.