# Compatibility Issues over inbuilt Android studio Styles for apps

Tags: android

I am using android studio version 1.0 .i would like to use my app's page without the `ActionBar` and `TitleBar` as well. How could I achieve that  only by extending my Activity to AppCompatActivity?

I tried changing all my necessary `AppThemes` and created my Custom `Theme` &`Styles`.

I have followed the [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat). Still I cannot get the full screen.

Comment: Just extend theme `*.NoActionBar`. If you need the fullscreen mode then set flags before start your activity. I can post you if it need.

Comment: ghostman ....Yes post it with pleasure.......Thanks

Comment: [Fullscreen modes](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/system-ui/immersive.html)

Comment: @ghostman  I need the short Explanations. How to enable in shortest way ....   Can you explain it.

Comment: It's already shortest way `<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>`

Comment: Post your xml of activity and styles. It must works.