# Android remove action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-styles

I'm trying to disable the action bar for some of my activities, but no matter what I try I can't seem to remove it.

In my styles.xml I have:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And in my manifest.xml I have:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".NewActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
</application>
```

My activity layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_new"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My app_bar_new layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="net.binarysea.sensorload.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_new" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want the action bar to display on activities apart from one (NewActivity). I use intents to call up NewActivity, at which point I thought it would load up the AppTheme.NoActionBar style, but the bar still appears on the screen

I'm using the navigation drawer activity in android studio if that makes a difference

EDIT: I've tried all the suggesting adding Adding `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`, but that only makes my action bar white and doesn't actually remove it. I tested this in a new android studio project, created a navigation drawer activity, and add the theme setting to my styles.xml. I still get the same problem

Comment: `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"` gets rid of it on my app. Put it in the appropriate activity

Comment: post your avtivity_layout.xml

Comment: Do you expect like this..http://s1285.photobucket.com/user/imagamechanger_silambarasan/media/device-2016-02-25-130209_zpse87tkzns.png.html?sort=3&o=1

Comment: I have added my layout files. And yes, that is what I want (apart from the hamburger and settings icons)

Answer (score 12):

Try this...

Just add **parent** tag for your style.

**Styles.xml**

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 </style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
 .......

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

     <activity
        android:name=".NewActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
      </activity>
   </application>
    ........
```

Comment: Adding `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` only makes the actionbar white, it doesn't remove it. Please see my edit

Answer (score 3):

Try and drop the following into your manifest
`android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: Adding `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` only makes the actionbar white, it doesn't remove it. Please see my edit

Answer (score 3):

MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); //will hide the title
    getSupportActionBar().hide(); // hide the title bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); //enable full screen
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow this Link- https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status

**Hide the Status Bar on Android 4.1 and Higher-Kotlin**

```
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
supportActionBar?.hide()
```

Better use it inside onResume().

**Another Solution**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28125711/14366835

Answer (score 0):

Use like this in styles.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/drawer_bg</item>

</style>
```

Create seperate layout for toolbar

toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In any activity, access this toolbar by using below code.

```
Toolbar toolbar; //declaration
```

In onCreate() after setContentView() use this

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: the manifest file and styles file you used will remove the action bar, to replace action bar with tool bar, use my code. It will add the toolbar in your activity

Comment: Adding `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` only makes the actionbar white, it doesn't remove it. Please see my edit

Comment: set windowNoTitle to false in styles

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your onCreate() of NewActivity to hide the action bar for particular Activity

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```