# Android Bottom Sheet Layout XML

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, bottom-sheet

Hello there I am trying to implement a simple Android Bottom sheet and my used xml is as follow!

### MY XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

           <Button
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:text="Effects"
              android:id="@+id/effects"
              android:textStyle="italic"/>

    <!--contains my layout for buttons, nested layout etc etc-->
    </LinearLayout

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:id="@+id/color_effects_bottom_sheet"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="350dp"
       android:clipToPadding="true"
       app:behavior_hideable="true"
       android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
      app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Please Set the Color Effects here!"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

---

The Code behind this XML is as Follow

### Code Behind

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
//Variables for bottom sheets calls
private Button btn_effects;
private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
private CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout;
////////////////////////////////////

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //locate coordinator layout
    coordinatorLayout=(CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_content);

    //locate bottom sheet
    View color_bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById( R.id.color_effects_bottom_sheet);

    //View scene_bottomSheet = coordinatorLayout.findViewById( R.id.scenes_bottom_sheet);

    //effects button
    btn_effects=(Button)findViewById(R.id.effects);

    //scenes button
    btn_scenes=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scenes);

    //settings button
    btn_settings=(Button)findViewById(R.id.settings);

    //bottom sheet behavior
    mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(color_bottomSheet);

    //effects button listener
    btn_effects.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        }
    });

}
```

}

---

### The Problem

The problem is that when i try to run this code it crashes my App and throws this Exception all the time.

### The Exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.bottomsheetexample, PID: 22875 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bottomsheetexample/com.example.bottomsheetexample.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2469)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:640)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:409)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:358)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1959)
at com.example.junaidhassan.bottomsheetexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5310)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2381)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2469)at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:409) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:358) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1959) 
at com.example.bottomsheetexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5310) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2381) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2469)at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:182)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:176)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:614) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:409) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:358) 
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:305) 
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1959) 
at com.example.bottomsheetexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23) 
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5310) 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2381) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2469)at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5551) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:914) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

### Need

Basically I am trying to implement Bottom Sheets for the first time. I want to add multiple Bottom Sheets to learn how to use them in the Application.

My Activity is a Full Screen Activity with the following App Theme

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
```

I want to use the Full Screen Activity and want to implement multiple Bottom Sheets on Button Click Listeners!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
   <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 </style>
```

I have to set a Custom Style to use a full screen activity to use multiple Bottom Screen!

### The Whole Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/main_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

           <Button
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:text="Effects"
              android:id="@+id/effects"
              android:textStyle="italic"/>

           <!--contains my layout for buttons, nested layout etc etc-->
    </LinearLayout

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       android:id="@+id/color_effects_bottom_sheet"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="350dp"
       android:clipToPadding="true"
       app:behavior_hideable="true"
       android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Please Set the Color Effects here!"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>


 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/second_bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

       <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:text="Please Set the Scene Effects here!"
         android:padding="16dp"
         android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

The thing is that one can invoke the second bottom sheet same as of the first bottom sheet.

My problem was to use full screen activity, and was using non AppCompat Theme and Activity. So I used a custom style themed activity and here it goes!

Answer (score 0):

As its stated in Your crashlog 
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library` change your app theme to one mentioned above

Comment: I want to use a Full Screen Activity Theme!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity. For fullscreen try link below http://stackoverflow.com/a/25365193/598641

Answer (score 0):

Add below line to your app-gradle if using android studio:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```