# howto get full screen activity in android studio

Tags: java, android

Am trying to make an splash screen and i want it to be full screen, no toolbar nothing, for that i changed the theme of the splashscreen.xml to full screen and in the design view everything seems perfect but when i launch the app on emulator it comes up again with the toolbar.

*My androidmenifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shiftind.www.shiftind">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".registration" />
        <activity android:name=".login" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUp" />
    </application>

</manifest>

*My splashscreen.xml*

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.shiftind.www.shiftind.SplashScreen"
    android:background="@drawable/shiftind">



</RelativeLayout>
```

*My SplashScreen.java*

```
package com.shiftind.www.shiftind;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        Thread MyThread = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    sleep(3000);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        MyThread.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this topic can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android ?

Answer (score 3):

Try defining the theme manually and setting the properties there. In `themes.xml`:

```
<style name="MyThemeNoBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And in `AndroidManifest.xml`, set the theme of SplashScreen to:

```
android:theme="@style/MyThemeNoBar"
```

**Edit**: I've also added `android:windowFullscreen` and `android:windowContentOverlay` (source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25365193/3474282)

Comment: I've just added a couple of extra possibly useful properties

Answer (score 0):

Your AndroidManifest was broken, here are corrections:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".registration" />
    <activity android:name=".login" />
    <activity android:name=".SignUp" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this programmatically ([see android samples](https://developer.android.com/samples/BasicImmersiveMode/src/com.example.android.basicimmersivemode/BasicImmersiveModeFragment.html)):

```
public void toggleHideyBar() {
    // The UI options currently enabled are represented by a bitfield.
    // getSystemUiVisibility() gives us that bitfield.
    int uiOptions = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getSystemUiVisibility();
    int newUiOptions = uiOptions;
    boolean isImmersiveModeEnabled =
            ((uiOptions | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY) == uiOptions);
    if (isImmersiveModeEnabled) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Turning immersive mode mode off. ");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Turning immersive mode mode on.");
    }

    // Immersive mode: Backward compatible to KitKat (API 19).
    // Note that this flag doesn't do anything by itself, it only augments the behavior
    // of HIDE_NAVIGATION and FLAG_FULLSCREEN.  For the purposes of this sample
    // all three flags are being toggled together.
    // This sample uses the "sticky" form of immersive mode, which will let the user swipe
    // the bars back in again, but will automatically make them disappear a few seconds later.
    newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    newUiOptions ^= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(newUiOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am using below thing which is fulfill my requirement !!

In Activity use below code in Oncreate method

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

and in your set your style as below

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>


    </style>

</resources>
```

if still have confusion mention in comment please :-)