# Cordova app full screen not working properly in some android device

Tags: cordova

I am using Cordova to make a mobile application. I want the app to take fullscreen (no header, no bottom bar). Even after using plugins for fullscreen and a fullscreen true in config file, the app is not taking fullscreen in some android devices (working fine in other). It shows a black strip in bottom, but when device is rotated (landscape mode) and again back to original position (portrait mode) it takes full screen. Please help.

Comment: I possible solution is here:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389547/full-screen-without-navigation-status-bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389547/full-screen-without-navigation-status-bars)