# Android - Making activity full screen with status bar on top of it

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar

I want to make my activity full screen with status bar on top of it  like this picture:

[image]

I have used this code in `manifest` inside `activity` tag:

```
'android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"'
```

But my view doesn't start from the status bar & it looks like this:

[image]

How can I make my `activity` look like the first one?

Comment: make status bar color transparent and add fitsystemwindow=true in image and top layout

Comment: @Utshaw, have you got a solution. if yes then please help me. require same implementation

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I know that the guy asking the question may have found his own solution but for the people who are still looking for a solution this is a very simple solution but one thing it has a limitation till `Kitkat` so a condition is added

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
}
```

Comment: @AsadMukhtar unfortunately, it does not

Comment: How i achieve this on pre kitkat?

Comment: @AsadMukhtar I think you should google about immersive full screen.

Comment: You want ContextMenu with icons? Woops goes out of screen. You want keyboard to adjustResize? HAHAHA NO!   

With `OnApplyWindowInsetsListener` this works like a charm, but it causes problems in other parts.

Comment: Works great! Removing other themes from interrupting this code worked.

Comment: The screen is not scrolling after implementing above snippet.

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work on Android 29, navbar appears on top of views

Comment: Sorry @BekaBot for that I will check and see if there is an alternative here

Comment: It's working but bottom navigation view goes behind navigation bar

Comment: One problem with this is it also overlaps the navigation button at the bottom.

Comment: @AshutoshSagar how to do above Navigation ?

Comment: I want it like tiktok which is above NavigationBar. SO how to achieve that?

Comment: @bdevloper you want it to cover the navigationbar as well right?

Comment: Didnt any one had problem scrolling when using this??????????

Answer (score 59):

Add these to your **Base Application Theme** in `styles.xml`

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

And add following attribute to your parent layout:

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
```

Comment: and will affect every activity

Comment: `android:fitsSystemWindows=”true”`, this isn't working for me.

Comment: Only works if I DON'T use android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

Comment: It should be android:fitsSystemWindows="false". I posted an edit, awaiting review now. Otherwise this is the correct answer.

Comment: using : 
   ' <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>'
also covers the bottom navigation bar,

Answer (score 20):

If you dont want your "Translucent navigation" transparent, here is the code to **just make transparent the status bar**

In your theme:

```
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

In your activity onCreate:

```
Window window = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = window.getAttributes();
winParams.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
window.setAttributes(winParams);
window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: saved my time, was searching for this for hours. +1

Comment: not working for me. my content goes behind navigation bar

Comment: How would I change the text and icon color? Its black by default

Comment: @bdevloper dont remember it now. dont even remember for what i was searching this.

Comment: Kotlin Code:
        val window: Window = window
        val winParams: LayoutParams = window.attributes
        winParams.flags = winParams.flags and LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS.inv()
        window.attributes = winParams
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN

Answer (score 14):

#### 1. Transparent Statusbar

```
window?.decorView?.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN)
window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
```

[image]

#### 2. Transparent Statusbar & Bottomnav bar

```
    window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
    );
```

[image]

#### 3. Hide Statusbar

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
    }
    else {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
    }
```

[image]

#### 4. Hide Statubar & Bottomnav bar

```
val actionBar: ActionBar? = supportActionBar
          if (actionBar != null) actionBar.hide()
         window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION)
```

[image]

**where to put this code ?**

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        /*  Put above code here ..... */
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slider)
   }
```

**Note**

- I checked this code in Pixel 3A emulator
- Maybe customise android OS not support
- set styel `<style name="Theme.FullScreen" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">`

Comment: Its not working exact in customize os suppose color os and <iui

Comment: Any ideas how to do that while keeping the action bar? I want to keep the action bar but merge it with the status bar.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
To achieve something similar to this, use this:

**1. Your Activity Theme**

```
<style name="FullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

**2. There is NO NEED to add `android:fitsSystemWindows` property into your root layout XML file.**

**3. In your Activity**

Add padding top to your toolbar. I am using custom toolbar, so I am adding padding to my toolbar of the height of statusbar.

```
toolbar.setPadding(0, getStatusBarHeight(), 0, 0)
```

and the function `getStatusBarHeight()` is added in my `Utils class`

```
fun Activity.getStatusBarHeight(): Int {
val resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android")
return if (resourceId > 0) resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId)
else Rect().apply { window.decorView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(this) }.top
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Put below code inside onCreate()

```
private void setStatusBarTransparent() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        View decorView = window.getDecorView();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
        } else {
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```

Comment: deprecated answer!

Comment: @KishanSolanki No man, it works on my device.

Comment: this code is deprecated if you use kotlin

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin just use following code in your activity, also add android:fitsSystemWindows="true" in your parent view of activity.xml layout file.
This will also show content over navigation bar too, provided you declared full screen style in your style.xml

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
     window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        )
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code after onCreate

```
   setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
```

Your activity will be fullscrean with status bar.

Answer (score -2):

@**tahsinRupam** answer is correct and tested on post Kitkat version.

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

If you want to use it only for a certain activity, create a style, and attach it on your manifest style like this.

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Activity.Fullscreen.Theme" />

<style name="Activity.Fullscreen.Theme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">  
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -3):

Put this code in your Activity onCreate this will hide the status bar

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```