# android show status bar when fullscreen mode

Tags: android, android-notification-bar, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar

I have some trouble scroll down status(notification) bar.

this is my code

```
try{
    Object sbservice = context.getSystemService( "statusbar" );
    Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName( "android.app.StatusBarManager" );
    Method showsb;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
    }
    else {
        showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
    }
    showsb.invoke( sbservice );
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This works fine except one.....

I am trying to make a overLay button to open the status bar in other apps.

It works fine except when another app is in fullcreen.
....

I found the fullscreen is above opened status bar.

So if I close the app, I can see the opened bar.

Is there any way to make the opened status bar is on top?

I am sorry bad english. and insufficient explanation....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Making activity full screen with status bar on top of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511326/android-making-activity-full-screen-with-status-bar-on-top-of-it)

Comment: i don't like to hide status bar. i want show that