# Creates a full screen activity but retains the notification bar

Tags: java, android, fullscreen

I'm creating a music application when designing kits, I think I need to create a full screen activity I have tried

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

But that's not what I want, I want full screen but still retain notification bar

[image]

How to do this?

Thank!

Comment: You can set it in `AndroidMenifest.xml`

Comment: @Binh Cao try my answer

Comment: You want that Notification Bar will stay visible??

Comment: yes i want the notification bar to still show up on my app

Comment: @Bink Cao check my new answer

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos it did not work

Comment: @BinhCao yes try to replace your styles.xml and ad this line in parent layout of your activity, check my answer for the code

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos You can see my edited photos in the post

Comment: yes take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511326/android-making-activity-full-screen-with-status-bar-on-top-of-it

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos Yes, it worked very good, thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
```

In your activity onCreate:

```
Window window = getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = window.getAttributes();
winParams.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
window.setAttributes(winParams);
window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: It hides the notification bar

Comment: try my new answer, i thought you want to hide bar so check my new answer

Comment: @BinhCao my answer very simpler :)

Comment: @BinhCao accept my answer if its possible, have a nice day coding

Comment: sorry i was trying the Paraskevas Ntsounos way then

Answer (score 1):

Remove `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` this line from your code and just put change int your activity style.

```
   <style name="LoginTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Manifest.xml

```
  <activity android:name=".Login"
        android:theme="@style/LoginTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this code above `setContentView()`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
```

Comment: It hides the notification bar