# Android R hide statusbar -> move view down and a black rectangle appears

Tags: android, fullscreen, statusbar, android-11

Android R + Pixel 4 Emulator : When I hide the status bar, the main view move down and a black square (same size as status bar) appears at the top.
It was working before Android 11.
It look simple but I'm not able to find a solution... And I need a fullscreen mode.

I tried with the SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN (that is now deprecated) and the controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
The two ways have the same issue.

[image]

Here is the main code:
MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonShow = findViewById(R.id.b1);
    buttonShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
           showBars();
        }
    });

    Button buttonHide = findViewById(R.id.b2);
    buttonHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          hideBars();
        }
    });

    showBars();
}

public void showBars(){

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions =  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

    // New code For Android 11, same effect...
    /*
    WindowInsetsController controller = getWindow().getInsetsController();
    if(controller != null) {
        controller.show(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
        controller.show(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
        controller.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
    }*/
}

public void hideBars(){


    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;


    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

    // New code For Android 11, same effect...
    /* WindowInsetsController controller = getWindow().getInsetsController();
      if(controller != null) {
          controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
          controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
          controller.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
      }*/

}
```

}

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="show" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hide"
/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you have to apply these code
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511326/android-making-activity-full-screen-with-status-bar-on-top-of-it

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:
Create a style resource file with v27 configuration for the activities you want in fullscreen and without cutout:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.ActivityFullscreenNoCutout">
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
</style>
```

And assign the style to your activity in the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp.ActivityFullscreenNoCutout"/>
```

Link: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout

If you have an action/app bar, you'll have to add the toolbar to your activity and not use the default one.

Link: https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up

Comment: Thank you so much. I put it directly in to theme and worked fine too:

<item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>

Comment: Thanks Arun! This is how it worked for me: <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="o_mr1">shortEdges</item>

Comment: It worked directly in theme for me too like @arun - how do you set v27 configuration though? Is that increasing minSdkVersion to 27? Is this required? I was hoping to target 24+

Comment: It is not required and doesn't increase the minSdkVersion. Creating a separate resource file lets you separate the code between the different configurations you want. The configuration in your theme file will just be ignored for api 26 and below.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in activity code...

```
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R) 
void hideStatusBar_with_API30() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    // Order swiped status bar to appear semitransparent.
    // If you do not that
    //  then once appeared bar will not disappear after nor few seconds nor you gesture.
    decorView.getWindowInsetsController().setSystemBarsBehavior(
            WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
    // Hide the status bar.
    decorView.getWindowInsetsController().hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
    // The status bar is allowed to appear with a swipe gesture.
    // When it is then app layout is resized.
    // To prevent changing the layout, you need to add:
    getWindow().setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false);
    // The status bar will appear over stable layout
}
```