# How to hide ActionBar with Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-actionbar, android-jetpack-compose, user-experience

I want to hide default action bar, so in the Manifest file I have following code:

```
    <style name="Theme.MyCompose" parent="Theme.Material.DayNight.NoActionBar">
</style>

<style name="Theme.Material.DayNight.NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />
```

And the effect is like this:

[image]

What I want to achieve is like this:

[image]

The photography should cover white area. How to accomplish that?

**UPDATE 1**

After implementing solution with Translucent Status Bar and Accompanist Insets support, I've encountered stranger behawior. When window flags are set as follow:

```
 window.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )
```

Everything looks like this although insets are on:
[image]

When removing those flags, insets works but I've that shadow:

[image]

Comment: That white area is not the action bar. That is the status bar. You need a full-screen theme for that if you want the effect all the time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need to hide status bar completely, you need to use a full screen theme, like showed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25365193/3585796)

---

[Since](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.2.0-alpha03) Compose **1.2.0-alpha03**, **Accompanist Insets** was mostly moved into Compose Foundation, check out [migration guide](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/#migration) for more details. The main changes to below answer is that `ProvideWindowInsets` is no longer needed and some imports should be replaced.

---

If you need a transparent status bar, you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311321/3585796), plus setup [Accompanist Insets](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/) for compose like following:

```kotlin
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
window.setFlags(
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
)
```

Then in compose you can set your image as background and offset from status/navigation bars using `systemBarsPadding` and other [Accompanist Insets](https://google.github.io/accompanist/insets/) modifiers.

```kotlin
setContent {
    ProvideWindowInsets {
        ComposePlaygroundTheme {
            Box {
                Image(
                    painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_image),
                    contentDescription = "...",
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                )
                Column(
                    Modifier.systemBarsPadding()
                ) {
                    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                        Text("Hello")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: @amtrax `setFlags` is needed to remove status bar background, so it won't have dark shadow. What's wrong with `setFlags` in your case?

Comment: please check post  update.

Comment: @amtrax sure you're using `Modifier.systemBarsPadding()` for your buttons container? And `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` is called in your activity? Also what android are you using?

Answer (score 3):

There's a new [EdgeToEdge](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/EdgeToEdge) solution for making your System Bars (StatusBar/NavigationBar) completely transparent.

Be sure that you're using compose.activity dependency of at least **1.8.0**:

```
 implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
```

Add this code in your **onCreate()** method of the activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    enableEdgeToEdge(
        statusBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
            Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT
        ),
        navigationBarStyle = SystemBarStyle.light(
            Color.TRANSPARENT, Color.TRANSPARENT
        )
    )
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
}
```

And your root composable should look something like this:

```
    ...
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = Color.Transparent.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = !darkTheme
        }
    }
    ...
```

You can also check this video tutorial: https://youtu.be/pLMw9Vlbfgw