# ActionBar in Android Studio. How to get rid of it entirely, while being able to preview the top part in ActivityMain.xml (design preview)

Tags: android, kotlin, material-ui, material-design, android-sdk-2.3

as the title suggests.. Want to make an activity with no top (actionBar) while also being able to see how that part of the screen will look like (in preview ActivityXml -> DesignPreview).
Thanks!
Writing in Kotlin trying to use Material.io

Comment: Forgot to mention ->
//IF possible to have a preview of the WHOLE screen when disabling the ActionBar.
Thank you!

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653305/full-screen-theme-for-appcompat