# Fullscreen no status bar style

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-flamingo

i am trying to make my app full screen but it is not working.. i am using the latest version of android studio (Flamingo).

```
<style name="Theme.MyQuizApp" parent="android:Theme.Material" >
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>



</style>
```

Comment: Please check this answer, if it suits your needs:
[Full Screen Theme for AppCompat thread at stackovrflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25365193/13755907)