# How can I use startLockTask() method for versions of Android Lower than L

Tags: android, api

I was using `startLockTask()` in a program but found out it could only be used for Android L.  However I want my application to function in versions lower then 5.

Is there any way I can gain similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functionally, no.  The point of screen pinning is to prevent the user from leaving your app. The user can't see or click on notifications, or use the home button to leave.

Visually, you [can set the app to full screen,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android), and/or [hide notification bar](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/status.html). You can also [hide the soft keys on devices that don't have hardware buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291640/how-to-hide-the-soft-key-bar-on-android-phone).  However, people can always bring it back up.

EDIT: You can also [disable the back button.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Comment: Do you think that if I release an app specifically for Lollipop that I would get a considerable amount of downloads if it costs 99 cents

Comment: Not right now.  Lollipop currently has < 0.1% of the userbase. Although HTC and Samsung are going to update their phones within the next year as well as release a bunch of new flagships, so it shouldn't discourage you to make it if screen pinning is absolutely needed. (It'll give you time to iron out all the wrinkles).

Comment: Right I'll get to that, I can wait, I'm developing to fund an around the world trip in maybe 5 years, but this is all I can do as a high schooler