# Hide Soft-keys in android and not to show even on user interaction during the app

Tags: android, android-activity, hide, show-hide

Note: Please don't close this question as duplicate as the other answers only hide the softkey bar [navigation bar at the bottom with 3 control buttons] till the user interaction is not there.

Hi, 
I am developing a paint app in which the user can draw similarly as in MS-paint.

To use the full estate of user's screen, I wish to hide the softkeys bar while the user is drawing or painting anything.

**So, I know how to hide the soft-keys bar but on user interaction [on Any interaction] the soft-keys bar appear on the screen. [Before lollipop]**

Is there any way that I can hide the soft-keys bar and they only appear after the user has exited from the app. **[I think I have seen this happening in some of the games]**

Note: somewhere it was also stated that the OS shows the soft-keys bar so that some goofy app doesn't ruin user's experience.

Any lead will be appreciated.

Updates:
1. This is the link that I had followed earlier: [How to hide the soft-key bar on Android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16291640/how-to-hide-the-soft-key-bar-on-android-phone)

2. By soft-keys bar I mean the navigation bar at the bottom of the screen as shown in the question in point 1.

Thanks.

Comment: when it is opening ??

Comment: @AnkitKumar Sorry, but haven't understood your question properly. If you are asking that when does the soft-keys open, the answer is any user interaction. Even if I touch the screen, the soft-keys will come on the screen and the app's estate decreases. I have also updated the question. Please check.

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hide The Keyboard with InputMethodManager and Set EditText Focusable False Will do the trick. Below code will hide the Keyboard and set EditText focusable as False.

```
 editText1.setFocusable(false);
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
                              Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText1.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

To Make EditText Editable Again, Use

```
editText1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText1.setFocusable(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Do this for ur activity in Manifest where u don't want to see Android Keypad:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize" 
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

2) Override these method call backs of Android for views that has on click and on focus listeners(like edit texts):

```
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus)
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
public void onClick(View v)


if(!hasFocus) {
InputMethodManager imm =  (InputMethodManager)  getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

the above focus check u do in focus change method and onclick, and call view.perform() in onTouch.

thats it..u can hide at all time.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question, basically I wish to hide the navigation bar at the bottom of the screen. Can you suggest something for that ?

Comment: Surely, i too need to workaround to "hide the navigation bar at the bottom of the screen"..

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void hideSoftKeyboard() {
    if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

Use this method to hide keyboard it has focus.