# Hide soft-key bar in activity theme

Tags: android, hide, android-theme, softkeys

[image: Soft-key bar]

I want to hide the soft-key bar (in devices that showing it) when my activity is shown. I can't do it programmatically like answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16291640/5318303), for some reasons. I only have access to activity's theme (`styles.xml`).

---

My main problem is to don't want activity's background (`android:windowBackground`) goes under the soft-keys bar. But it is better to **removing the bar completely**.

Comment: Soft keys cannot be completely hidden. It would limit the user on leaving the app when he/she wants to

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found so far, is to make `navigationBarColor` transparent like below. But it has some issues.

```
<style name="SplashScreenAppTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
</style>
```