# How to capture the "softkey show/hide" event in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, navigationbar, softkeys

In my case I hide softkeys in the app but at sometimes softkeys show and hide when displaying notifications. In my code I used,

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Is there any listener or callback to detect when softkeys show/hide event.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try Using OnFocusChangeListener() on the Edit Text:

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus){
            InputMethodManager imm = 
(InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }               
    }
});
```

Comment: thanx.. but I'm talking about softkeys just use for back and menu not for soft keyboard..

Comment: ohh. ok. Have you tried onWindowFocusChanged?? Check this answer:
 [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966855/6345864)

Comment: Yes.. I try it. but It can't detect the softkey hide event.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

> OnGlobalLayoutListener

to catch the event

```
contentView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {

      //try catching soft keys here
    }
    });
```

Comment: thanx.. but I'm talking about softkeys just use for back and menu not for soft keyboard..