# Android - How to unhide soft buttons after programatically hiding them?

Tags: java, android, android-softbuttons

Some android phones have soft buttons (back, home, menu). I manage to hide them using `setSystemUiVisibility` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36966855/9640177).

However, how to make the softbuttons visible pragmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [**`setSystemUiVisibility()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSystemUiVisibility(int))

- Request that the visibility of the status bar or other screen/window decorations be changed.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tvTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tvTextView=findViewById(R.id.tvTextView);
        tvTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE` worked for me.

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);
```