# Is it possible to prevent the navigation bar on Android <4.4?

Tags: java, android, navigationbar

In my application I want to prevent the display of the navigation bar. In Android 4.4 it's easy to implement (see here: [How to hide navigation bar permanently in android activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21724420/how-to-hide-navigation-bar-permanently-in-android-activity)), but lower versions can't do this.

I saw a similar mechanism in some players which hide navigation bar in fullscreen without any possibility to display it when the screen is touched.

I would be grateful for tips or code samples as it can be done.

Thank you.

Comment: Not without root access or some fancy hackery: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445157/easy-way-to-hide-system-bar-on-android-ics)

Answer (score 0):

*SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION* is available since API level 16.
So it works since Android 4.1+. You have to remember to reset this flag every time the user makes the NavigationBar show up again.

Only the immersive mode is only available since 4.4