# Can I hide the status bar in android completely by using root permissions?

Tags: android, root

I want to hide the status bar completely. I have seen we can do some very great things by getting root permissions. So is it possible that I can hide the status bar by using root permissions?

Comment: Psiible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958034/hide-tablet-system-bar

Answer (score 0):

To hide a status Bar

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: Will it let me hide the status bar completely even though other apps are opened?