# True fullscreen in AIR on Android?

Tags: android, mobile, air, fullscreen, tablet

I am developing an interactive video application using AIR on Android. The application is for at-risk communities to encourage them to get common cancer screenings, and will be deployed in clinics.  I am testing and eventually deploying on the ASUS TF300, a 1280x800 ICS tablet.

When I put the app in fullscreen mode through a variety of methods it looks great, except the bottom bar of buttons does not hide, and instead displays as a black bar with "stealth" dots where the buttons normally present.  I need to completely hide this bar so that users will not inadvertently navigate to home or other Android views.

I am having trouble solving this problem because I am not sure - Is it possible to EVER hide this bottom bar in ICS?  If so, is there a known method for achieving this in AIR?

Many thanks for any advice.

related - what is the official name for this bottom bar of buttons in ICS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name is system bar.

http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/ui-overview.html

Unless you are using a rooted device you can't really removed them as they are user navigation controls.

See this SO question:
[Is there a way to hide the system/navigation bar in Android ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926767/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-navigation-bar-in-android-ics)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, where I had to hide the system bar in a digital signage app for Android sticks for TV. I used [distriqt native extension](http://distriqt.com/) called [Application](http://distriqt.com/native-extensions#application).

Then it was as simple as using UI_NAVIGATION_HIDE in ApplicationDisplayModes class along with FULLSCREEN in my init function.

Just so you know, it is a paid extension, but worth buying the package as you get a lot of other good stuff along with it. I wasn't sure on where to begin with building my own ANE, so I went with distinqt.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be possible. After a few days of beating my head against the wall, I have this working on a cheap, Chinese android stick running ICS. The gist is that you need to create an Adobe Native Extension that runs the follow lines of Java:

```
Window window = context.getActivity().getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Of course, you need about a dozen files of boilerplate to run those lines. Here's a good [tutorial on building native extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/building-ane-ios-android-pt1.html).