# Hide System navigation bar on android tablet 3.0+

Tags: android, hide, navigationbar

I am working on an app which will be installed on tablets placed in public places like corners, shops. I want to hide the system navigation bar for restricting users from playing around in tablet. Is there any way to do this either programmatically or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is already an answer to your question here: [Is there a way to hide the system/navigation bar in Android ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926767/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-navigation-bar-in-android-ics)

I will just add that on some devices SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION does not work in that case you need to change some configurations in android itself to add the feature or maybe you can use ile's answer.