# How, Android Bottom Navigation Bar hide permanently or disable

Tags: android, security, pos, android-bottomnav

[image]

my requirement(security purpose) is when user log into my app he is not allow to

1. close app
2. navigate to another app
3. not allow to change setting

so to fulfilled this requirement i want to

1. Hide Bottom navigation Bar (or)
2. disable Bottom navigation bar

i try to hide bottom navigation bar using this code

```
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION ;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

but when i touch screen again Bottom navigation reappear

This is banking app banking people requesting to do that if there any possibility 
do this task or if you have any other solution please give me

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-in-an-activity/26013850 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471490/disabling-and-hiding-android-navigation-bar-notification-menu-permanently

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android

Comment: you should not be able to implement what you want. That is totally not up to you to decide if user can exit your app.

Comment: i am developing banking application for sunmi pos device banking people requesting for me to use there application only this pos device

Comment: then you probably can gain a root access on that device, or use a kiosk mode. Or develop your app as a launcher app on it.

Answer (score 2):

It can not be permanently hidden- it would be android security issue

Comment: any other suggestion to do my task?

Comment: @damithalahakoon, if your app is a generic 3rd-party app that any user can install from google play, even if you would be able somehow to implement what you want, your app will be treated as malicious, and likely removed from google play.

Comment: i am developing banking application for sunmi pos device

Comment: KIOSK software would be your solution

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
View decor_View = getWindow().getDecorView();

int ui_Options = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
| View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

decor_View.setSystemUiVisibility(ui_Options);
```

But it need device android OS version is 4.4 or higher.