# How is it possible to show an image in a full screen on android?

Tags: android

I wan't to show an image that is already saved on the device. I want to show the image on the whole screen by accessing all the pixels on the screen of the android device.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your responses @akash93 and @ghostbust555.

I was looking for a way that I can wrap it with python script.

Here, what I found that helped me to figure out a solution for my problem.

To disable the navigation bar:

```
adb shell service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui
```

Show an image:

```
shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file://data/test.jpg -t image/jpeg
```

To enable the navigation bar:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d file://%s/test_lcd.jpg -t image/jpeg
```

Resource:
[Is there a way to hide the system/navigation bar in Android ICS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926767/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-system-navigation-bar-in-android-ics)

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for full screen immersive mode - https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html

Answer (score 0):

In your activity's `onCreate` method add

```
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

before `setContentView`