# SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION not working on Android 4.0.3

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationbar

I'm trying to hide navigation bar (back, home buttons) on an Android 4.0.3 tablet.

I've tested this code on android 4.3 emulator and it's working:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    View v = getWindow().getDecorView();
    v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
}
```

But it's doing nothing on my tablet !

I'm not sure if `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION` should work on 4.0.3 but I see that 
tablet's default video player on 4.0.3 is hiding the navigation bar and the behavior looks like it is using `SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`.

Is this code supposed to work on 4.0.3?

If not is there some alternative that I could use?

Comment: I've found [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804642/android-tablet-navigation-bar-wont-hide) that answers my question.
Moreover after taking a closer look I've found that tablet's default movie player is using SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE instead of SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION.
Probably as pointed out SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION is not working on android 4.0.3.

Comment: You may want to post that as an answer.....