# How do I dim the system bar in Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

How do I programatically dim the system bar in Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using the following code:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.myview);
v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this via XML? The reason I wish to do so is to change the functionality of existing compiled apps with only resource editing.

Comment: i have tried with the view that i set in contentview. but it's not working. any idea?

Comment: This should do the trick: "getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN )"

Comment: Since API 14 getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility( View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE ); is the prefered

Answer (score 1):

you can dim it using SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE but it will appear when user touch the bar. But you can disable it except home.

add this in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR"/>
```

inside onCreate()

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    View v = findViewById(R.id.home_view);
    v.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE);
```

where home_view is the parent view of xml file.

```
 @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            return false;
        }

 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
     {
             try
             {
                if(!hasFocus)
                {
                     Object service  = getSystemService("statusbar");
                     Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
                     Method collapse = statusbarManager.getMethod("collapse");
                     collapse .setAccessible(true);
                     collapse .invoke(service);
                }
             }
             catch(Exception ex)
             {
             }
     }
```

you can't capture the home event, the only thing is you can do is to give your application home category and let the user choose.

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801928/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-system-bar/15652646#15652646