# Make an app occupy all of the screen on a tablet in android 3.0 honeycomb? (on title bar and status bar)

Tags: android, fullscreen, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am making an app for android 3.0 and i need it to be fullscreen. currently the manifest file contains these two lines in activity tag:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

(for some reason i need to fix the orientation to portrait)

but the emulator shows a status bar at the bottom (or in this case right).

not allowed to post images but here is a link to the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAUCj.jpg

Is there any method to remove the status bar too....

Thanks

Shobhit

Comment: I saw this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2868047/fullscreen-activity-in-android) but as you can see it doesn't help my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove the system bar entirely because it is an essential part of the UI, and contains the back and home buttons. However, you can hide or "dim" it as explained in [How do I dim the system bar in Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883789/how-do-i-dim-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-honeycomb).