# How can I hide or remove the status bar in Android HoneyComb?

Tags: java, android, android-3.0-honeycomb

How can I hide or remove the status bar in Android HoneyComb?  Every time I run my application, I find some contents have to be covered by the status bar.

I have try to change the `AndroidManifest.xml`, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't. It's considered a permanent screen decoration in the same way that capacitive home/menu/etc. buttons below the touchscreen on Android phones are.

How are you measuring the space available for your content?

Answer (score 2):

You can only dim the status bar. See [How do I dim the system bar in Android 3.0 (Honeycomb)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883789/how-do-i-dim-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-honeycomb)