# Modifying the Android combined tablet bar

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

There exist several solutions (both legit and workaround) to allow the navigation bar to be hidden in smartphones and, in the case of https://stackoverflow.com/a/15227433/995285 there is even a magic flag that hides everything.  I have confirmed that solution as working on my Sony ExperiaZ running Android 4.1.2. Seemingly perfect.

Trouble is, I am involved in Android OS development and one requirement is that the combined bar be completely hidden while proprietary applications are running - this is for safety reasons - and I cannot, for the life of me, get the status bar to hide using the API.

My question, then, is what modifications need to be made to the Android OS to achieve this goal?  Could I derive the responsible class and use that as a replacement?  If I'm not mistaken, I'm looking at modifying the WindowManager, but I could be wrong...

We are, so far, limited to Android ICS 4.0.4 and so the aforementioned solution does not work - I tried and hoped...