# How to prevent android application interface from exiting

Tags: android

I'm developing an android application using *AppGyver* on a [HP E2P18AA](http://www.amazon.co.uk/HP-E2P18AA-ABU-SLATE-21-S100/dp/B00EXIX3YK) (Android 4.2).
I want to prevent the user from exiting the application(because the tablet will be in a public place), either by :

- Disabling the buttons and the naigation bar.
- Hiding the navigation bar permanently.

Or any other idea.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While you can override the device's back button, you probably cannot override device's home or application list buttons without rooting the Android OS.

Place the device inside a cover which prevents user from clicking those buttons. :D

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the `Navigation Bar` permanently using either **build.prop** file:

```
qemu.hw.mainkeys = 1 // write that line at the end of the file
```

**OR**

**adb command prompt:**

```
 adb shell >
 su >
 pm disable com.android.systemui >
```

and for more information about how to achieve that or how to edit build.prop file , refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26013850/1638739).