# Permanently hide bottom bar

Tags: android

I am working on custom screen lock app where we need to full screen view hiding the top and bottom bars completely. The app is for Android phones only and not tablets. I achieved this partially by using Immersive mode but the issue is the bottom bar & top appears for few seconds on touching bottom or top of the screen.

Below is the code in my activity to do this :

```
final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
```

I have tried various options but unable to hide the bars permanently. Please advise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permanently hide navigation bar on activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-on-activity)

Comment: I hope that it is not able to be achieved. If there is way, then apps like this can block the screen without any way to unblock it.

Comment: @metalurgus This is possible. Since I am working on Screen lock app, user would be able to enter only once correct password in entered. NextLock from Microsoft does the same.

Comment: @Simas Thanks for the reply. I had already checked this post and tried as suggested but no result. Seems I am missing some thing.