# How to hide Navigation Bar permanently in Jelly Bean (before KitKat) in Android Activity?

Tags: android, fullscreen, navigationbar, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I made a Full-Screen app for android which hides both Navigation Bar & Status Bar  that supports API 16 (starting from Jelly Bean)..
I know that if I want to hide both Navigation Bar & Status Bar starting from KitKat I can use the following code:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
```

But that code doesn't work for Jelly Bean, it hides the bars only once and they reappear once you touch the screen.
So I know that the following code supports Jelly Bean but it only hides the Status Bar:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Can anyone show me the way to hide the Navigation Bar as well on Jelly Bean permanently?

Comment: Please check the Android documentation https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permanently hide navigation bar on activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-on-activity)

Comment: I didn't find an answer to that, All I found was to be able to dim the Navigation Bar but not hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding statusbar/navigation bar once again after it appears on the screen.

Here is information how to listen for UI changes:

https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html

Relevant part:

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener
        (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
            // system bars are visible
            // hide them again, maybe with some delay?
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried this in onCreat() by adding this instead of the comments above:
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE);

Still doesn't work!

Comment: do you see this callback being called, ie add Log.d(...) and see if you have this message in the logs...

Comment: It doesn't show in the log, the whole method "onSystemUiVisibilityChange" isn't being called!