# How do you keep the Navigation Bar hidden when opening dialogs?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, navigationbar

I have a theme that has a `Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` parent. The thing is all my activities keeps the navigation bar hidden, but when a dialog is opened, it returns with a sometimes black and sometimes transparent background color. Is there a way to keep it hidden during opening dialogs?

Comment: Please add any Screenshot so we are able to get the point of Issue.

Comment: could you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-on-activity

Comment: As I have said above, it only happens to dialogs. All my activities automatically hides it using flags as well

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally solved this by overriding the `show()` method of the custom dialog that I have.

```
@Override
public void show() {
    // Set the dialog to not focusable.
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);

    // Show the dialog with NavBar hidden.
    super.show();

    // Set the dialog to focusable again.
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I used @John Ernest Guadalupe's idea to solve my same problem with an AlertDialog but with his solution the navigation bar popped up for a quarter second and after gone (nasty flick). I didn't like this so i used a little trick for eliminate it:

> Hide the navigation bar **before** showing the dialog.

```
// Flags for full-screen mode:
static int ui_flags =
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY |
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;

// Set up the alertDialogBuilder:
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setIcon(R.drawable.outline_info_black_48)
    .setTitle("Bla")
    .setMessage("Blaa blabla.")
    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

// Create the alertDialog:
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

// Set alertDialog "not focusable" so nav bar still hiding:
alertDialog.getWindow().
    setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);

// Set full-sreen mode (immersive sticky):
alertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(ui_flags);

// Show the alertDialog:
alertDialog.show();

// Set dialog focusable so we can avoid touching outside:
alertDialog.getWindow().
    clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```