# Hide system navigation bar when show DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

My app is in `sticky immersive mode` that the `system navigation bar` (I call it SNB) is hidden in running time of my app. It works well but exists one problem, it is each time I show a `DialogFragment`, the SNB will be appear. How can I hide it.

I have written a few line of code in my acivity class to make my app become fullscreen and `sticky immersive mode`.

> MyActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    hideSystemUI();
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    hideSystemUI();
}

public void hideSystemUI() {
    // Enables regular immersive sticky mode.
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    );
}
```

> MyDialog.java

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment{

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        AlertDialog alertD = builder.create();
        alertD.setView(view);
        return alertD;
    }

    public void show() {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        show(activity.getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes((WindowManager.LayoutParams) params);
    }
}
```

I followed the answer to show dialog without show SNB: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33589793/10467639 but it does not work as desired

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
// Set the dialog to not focusable.
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
dialog.show();
// Set the dialog to focusable again.
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
```

> style.xml

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/themeColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/themeColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/themeColor</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
    </style>
    <style name="BoldGrayHeaderTextView">
        <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunitosans_bold</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/darkColor</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Splash Screen theme. -->
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <!-- For CarPinItem on Map -->
    <style name="carPinItemUnSelected">
        <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunitosans_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/generalTextColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="carPinItemSelected">
        <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunitosans_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Style for drawer navigation item                                                                       -->
    <style name="NavigationDrawerStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item><!-- text size in menu-->
        <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item><!-- item size in menu-->
        <item name="listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item><!-- item size in menu-->
    </style>

    <!--Style for textInputEditText   -->
    <style name="TextInputLayoutStyle">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunitosans_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">13dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>

    </style>
    <!--Style for profile bottom menu   -->
    <style name="BottomTextLayoutStyle">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunitosans_regular</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/successColor</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.App.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>

    </style>

    <!--BottomNavivagionView textsize-->
    <style name="Widget.BottomNavigationView"
        parent="Widget.Design.BottomNavigationView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/nunitosans_regular</item>
    </style>

    <style name="NoActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank in advanced!

Comment: Hey can you also show your `styles.xml` file here.

Comment: @ravi I think the problem not cause by XML, the XML file actually is very long and confusing! It's just described my activity UI!

Comment: we should not really make assumptions about the cause of a problem. But if you think this much info gets your problem solved, well good luck.

Comment: @ravi I am sorry for my naive assumtion. I have edited my answer with `style.xml` file. Can you help me again?

Comment: It's alight man. I have posted an answer, try that and let me know if that helps

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/23207365/8531215 ,I have tested and it works fine! modify `onCreateDialog()` method a little bit

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        AlertDialog alertD = builder.create();
        alertD.setView(view);
        Dialog dialog = alertD.create();
        dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);

        //Show the dialog!
        dialog.show();

         //Set the dialog to immersive sticky mode
        dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        //Clear the not focusable flag from the window
        dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
        return alertD;
}
```

Comment: It worked, but in my scenario naviagation bar appear for less than a sec. Is there any solution for navigation bar to not to appear. I have a dialogfragment in player for video quality selection.

Comment: This is work solution which no need to touch style.xml and using IMMERSIVE_STICKY flag. With no STICKY there may be different scenario.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html):

> Implement onWindowFocusChanged(). If you gain window focus, you may want to re-hide the system bars. If you lose window focus, for example due to a dialog or pop up menu showing above your app, you'll probably want to cancel any pending "hide" operations you previously scheduled with Handler.postDelayed() or something similar.

So What I suggest you do is, change your code in `MyActivity.java` from:

```java
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    hideSystemUI();
}
```

to:

```java
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
     if (!hasFocus){
            //we lost focus due to DialogFragment
            hideSystemUI();            
        }
}
```