# NavigationBar not hide in Immersive Mode when show a DialogFragment with Navigation Component-Android Kotlin

Tags: android, navigation, navigationbar, dialogfragment, android-immersive

I'm a newbie and created a game on native Android with Kotlin (a big mistake).

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nochi.words

Since I believed it, I have had nothing but problems. And the problem I have that I cannot solve is hiding the Navigation Bar when I show a DialogFragment when i use Immersive Mode.

[Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgoQ9.png)

[Show DialogFragment with Navigation Gesture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiYUA.png)

[Show DialogFragment with Navigation Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyUAQ.png)

I use the Navigation Component to display the DialogFragment. It seems like no one on the internet is having the same problem or am I missing something.

```
game_graph.xml
...
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/settingsFragment"
        android:name="nochi.words.ui.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" >
</dialog>
...
```

This solution doesn't work for me because when I click on the DialogFragment it appears again:
[Hide system navigation bar when show DialogFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56986031/hide-system-navigation-bar-when-show-dialogfragment)

I'm thinking about switching to Unity if I can't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the lack of function code from description above, I don't know how you display or implement the DialogFragment.

For immersive mode, you can hide navigation bar by hiding system bars:

```
val windowInsetsController =
  WindowCompat.getWindowInsetsController(your_window, your_window.decorView)

// Hide the system bars.
windowInsetsController.hide(Type.systemBars())
```

- Use **Type.navigationBars()** to hide only the navigation bar.

Hope this is working for you.

Related Android documents:

- [Immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/edge-to-edge#immersive-mode)
- [Hide system bars for immersive mode](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive#kotlin)

If this answer not working, please provide more info of your code for others to clarify the problem. Good luck!