# How to permanently hide navigation bar in android application?

Tags: android, android-navigation

I have a problem hiding navigation bar at the bottom of the screen in android.
Every solution I've tried doesn't work exactly as I want it to work, except one.
Modifying build.prop with new entry 'qemu.hw.mainkeys=1' worked ok, but it disables navigation bar for whole android system.
Is there possibility to disable navigation bar like this only for one app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanently hide navigation bar on activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-on-activity)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide both the navigation bar and the status bar.
// SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN is only available on Android 4.1 and higher, but as
// a general rule, you should design your app to hide the status bar whenever you
// hide the navigation bar.
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

[(Source)](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Use this code in onCreate(), it will hide status bar and navigation bar until users swipe down from top of the screen