# Hide navigation bar permanently when i open my app android

Tags: android, hide

Don't close this question since this is very old but i cant find the solution.
I'm new to android. I want to disable the soft keys at the bottom and the status permanently once the user opens my app.

It should not appear even on user interaction.

```
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus){
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            }
        }
```

This code just hides the navigation bar. But when i swipe from the bottom it appears. This should not happen. Please help.

To come out of my app i will provide a way. 
Thanks

Comment: Try the answers on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-on-activity

Comment: R u coding in xamarin ?

Comment: This the closest solution I found https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85013/how-to-enable-task-locking-in-android-5-0-production-devices/85125#85125

Answer (score 0):

> Don't close this question since this is very old but i cant find the solution. I'm new to android. I want to disable the soft keys at the bottom and the status permanently once the user opens my app.
>
> It should not appear even on user interaction.

I am pretty sure you cannot disable the navigation bar permanently. Otherwise the user will be stuck with your app forever with no way of getting out of it.

Comment: Yes but i will provide something to come out of the app. I need to disable it permanently. How can i do it?

Comment: Android wont allow it. What if your implementation is buggy and you miss a special case. The user would be stuck