# How to permanantly disable system ui (navigation bar and status bar) in an android application?

Tags: android, system

Most of the answers I've found only temporarily disable these features, and then opening a soft keyboard or alert dialog shows them again.

The requirement: The end user of this device should not be able to navigate out of the application while it is running. Administrators can do this by using a private combination of physical keypad buttons, but otherwise the application should alway stay open.

...How can I do this? I've read that android does not allow the disabling of these features for security reasons, but can anyone give me an idea for a work-around?

Comment: Off the top of my head, maybe you could make the app replace the device's lockscreen... That brings other problems with it, though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanently hide navigation bar on activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-on-activity)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kiosk mode in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android)

Comment: Your device is rooted? If not, is not possible. (only temporally)