# How to perfectly hide the bottom navigation bar

Tags: java, android

I am developing an apps which needs enter full-screen mode,
however, no matter I tried. The bottom navigation bar is hidden but it will pop up for half second when I change the page (change activity). I really appreciate if someone can give me a hand, it troubles me for a day. Thank you!

Android OS 8.0 Oreo, Android Studio 3.1.4

Following codes are the java class, styles.xml and layout.xml, thanks!

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }


    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }
}
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Show the problematic code in order to get help. Otherwise, the answers might be too broad and probably too unspecific for your problem.

Comment: Without seeing your code all we can do is *guessing what may cause the issue*. Please, post your code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? and could you please explain your question with image and android-OS information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permanently hide Navigation Bar in an activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16713845/permanently-hide-navigation-bar-in-an-activity)

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: just update the codes, thank you very much!

Comment: I use these settings to achieve full-screen, is it right? But it has the bar pop up issue when changing the page

Comment: I have this problem too, have you found a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, this works for me :

```
protected void fullScreen() {
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    fullScreen();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    fullScreen();
}
```