# How to hide the navigation bar in android?

Tags: android

so i'm writing an app in which i would like the navigation bar in a specific 
activity to be hidden...and i managed to do so...but my problem is when the
user scrolls down the notification bar...when that happens...the navigation bar
re-appears...how can i solve this problem?

```
   final int mUIFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    //View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);
```

Comment: Did you try getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); in your Activity? Like @hata said, this is a normal behavior in Android. After a few seconds the navigation bar disappear again

Answer (score 1):

> when the user scrolls down the notification bar...when that happens...the navigation bar re-appears

I think this behavior is normal and intended as UI design of Android.

Whenever a user swipes-down upper edge or swipes-up bottom edge of screen, both system bar and navigation bar re-appear. Then after a few seconds, they are both disappear again. So as to the user can access system bar or navigation bar whenever they want even if screen is in immersive mode.

> can i do anything to disable this? or maybe only hide it

No, generally (without root access) you can't. Only you can do is to hide it. Please refer to these StackOverflow Q&As: [Permanently hide navigation bar on activity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16716301/3501958); [Hide System Bar in Tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12605313/3501958).

Comment: ok i understand that...the question is - can i do anything to disable this? or maybe only hide it...

Comment: @meirfranco Unfortunately, you can't. Please see my update.