# Android remove navigation bar

Tags: android, android-layout, navigationbar

Im facing a seriour problem.

Im developing an app for Android API 14 (>= Android 4.0). I test the app in some devices and work well but the devices that have a navigation bar inside the screen not work.
I saw some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605266/hide-system-bar-in-tablets/12605313#12605313) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883789/how-do-i-dim-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-honeycomb) but nothing work.

Here is an image of the navigation bar: [Image Navigation Bar](https://www.google.com.uy/search?q=navigation%20bar%20in%20android&espv=2&biw=1600&bih=775&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=dklvVbH7Hs7IsASa-oG4Ag&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ#imgrc=v189uGIJYaqARM%253A%3By8Byn83WYrQXPM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fdeveloper.xamarin.com%252Fguides%252Fandroid%252Fuser_interface%252Fnavigation_bar%252FImages%252F19_-_NavBar.png%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fdeveloper.xamarin.com%252Fguides%252Fandroid%252Fuser_interface%252Fnavigation_bar%252F%3B720%3B92)

I have two questions:

1) Is there a way to hide the navigation bar for ever? im developing a game, so i dont want to this bar appear. Which is the best solution? maybe not to hide and calc the size of the screen with navigation bar?

2) When im developing in the graphical layout i try to hide the navigation bar adding the Theme: Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen but the navigation stills there, so when i position some views, when i run the app in a device, the views are not in the correct position

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this, call in in your activity's onCreate

```
public void makeFullScreen() {
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { //View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE is only on API 19+
        this.getWindow().getDecorView()
                .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    } else {
        this.getWindow().getDecorView()
                .setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
    }
}
```