# Android Activity using navigation view in full screen mode shows at the bottom a grey translucent area

Tags: android, drawerlayout, navigationview, android-fullscreen

I have an **activity** which is using the following method to enable **fullscreen** mode.

```
protected void hideSystemUI() {

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

In this activity I am also using the **NavigationView** and when the **NavigationView** is visible at the bottom(where the navigation buttons are located) a **grey translucent** is visible.
My question is how can I hide this area.

[image]

[image]

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883789/how-do-i-dim-the-system-bar-in-android-3-0-honeycomb helps you.

Comment: I've  tried and did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing the flag `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE`from the method `hideSystemUI`. Now the method looks like this:

```
protected void hideSystemUI() {
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```