# Android AppCompatActivity: NavigationView in full screen shows grey bar at the bottom

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, navigationview, android-fullscreen

I have AppcompatActivity *(appcompat-v7:25.3.1)* which is in full screen mode using the below code. But the problem is that when in full screen mode and **navigationview** is displayed it shows these black overlay bar on top and bottom of it in Android 6.0, equal to the sizes of status bar and navigation bar.
[Navigation view after applying the below mentioned flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yZdz.png) (Can't embed images for now :( )

```
private void hideAndroidNavigation() {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
}
```

In Android 4.4 however the black overlay simply turns to white
[as you can see in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnIbr.png).

I was able to remove the overlay for the status bar using following code:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
```

But I have no luck for the removal of the navigation bar overlay. I tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/38008965/4428159, suggesting to **remove** View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE but still the output was same

Is there any other way to remove these overlays or a solution specific to appcompat libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the following line `fitSystemWindows=true` in your layout xml and style xml, if so remove the line or set the value to false