# NullPointException with getActionBar

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-3.0-honeycomb, tablet, android-actionbar

I have a really strange behaviour with my tablet interface (Android > 3).
When I launch it, it's like a Android 2* interface with the title at the bottom.
And of course when I call the getActionBar() it returns a null.

My min-sdk & target-sdk are well set and I use the SDK Android 3.0 (11). Where am I wrong ?

```
public class MainScreenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainlayout);
    ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbar));
```

With the last line I get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 9082):    at com.shoppingscanner.tablet.MainScreenActivity.onCreate(MainScreenActivity.java:21)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9082):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9082):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9082):    ... 11 more
```

My Manifest (Android 3.0 used) :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
```

Even if the minSdk is 11, I have this behaviour.

Thanks !

Comment: Try not using minsdk, just for test. Your code hardly support minsdk="5" if it works with actionbar...

Comment: @Warpzit Unfortunately that's the same :/

Comment: Now I'm just shooting :) I don't have experience with actionbar but from what I read maybe you should set the background in public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

Comment: You should also check for Your application theme. As in my case I was updating older application has theme set to Full screen no Title bar, which I guess was reason for actionBar null.

Comment: Try this and modify it according to your need
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914791/android-3-0-action-bar-dont-want-to-go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need your Activity's window to have the title visible. you can take help from
[here](http://blog.perpetumdesign.com/2011/08/strange-case-of-dr-action-and-mr-bar.html)